# Find all $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\ne k^2$ ($k\in\mathbb N$) and $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^3\mid n^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find all $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\ne k^2$ ($k\in\mathbb N$) and $$\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor^3\mid n^2$$

That's a really interesting problem and I can't seem to find an idea for a solution. Some help would be great. I need an idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to set $n=a^2+b$, with $0<b<2a+1$ and $a,b\in\mathbb N$.

The question becomes whether
$a^3\mid(a^2+b)^2$ holds, or equivalently, $a^3\mid2a^2b+b^2$.

This should help you further.

Comment: So we have to prove that $$\frac{2b}{a}+\frac{b^2}{a^3}=z$$
where $z\in\mathbb N$. That gives us the expression of $b$ in terms of $z$ and $a$, which is $$b=a^2(\sqrt{1+\frac{z}{a}}-1)$$
Also, since $1+\frac{z}{a}>1$, we have that $z>a$. But that doesn't tell me anything. How have you finished the solution?

Comment: I proved that from $p^k\mid a$ follows that $p^{3k}\mid b^2$ for odd primes $p$.

Comment: How to prove it?

Comment: Well we have if $p^k\mid a$, then $p^{2k}\mid a^3\mid 2a^2b+b^2$, so $p^{2k}\mid b^2$. Then $p^k\mid b$, so from $p^{3k}\mid 2a^2b+b^2$ it follows that $p^{3k}\mid b^2$. (It's true for $p=2$ too, not only for odd primes.)

Comment: Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and write $a=ud$, $b=vd$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1$. Then $u^3\mid 2u^2dv+v^2$, so any prime dividing $u$ also divides $v$. Hence $a\mid b$, so $b=a$ or $b=2a$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I had another solution in mind but yours works fine and is much shorter. Here's how I continued: from $p^k\mid a\Rightarrow p^{3k}\mid b^2$ it follows that $b^2\geq a^3$. This combined with $b\leq2a$ gives $a\leq4$. All you have to do next is check the cases $a\leq4$.

Comment: @barto It's still hard for me to understand this proof. Why did you  choose a degree of a prime number rather than just a simple divisor?

Comment: In order to estimate the size of $b$, it isn't enough to know its prime divisors. Suppose, for example we could conclude that every prime divisor of $a$ divides $b$. That doesn't allow us to conclude $b^2\geq a^3$ or something. There are many terrible cases like $a=(2\cdot3)^{500}$ and $b=2\cdot3$. To estimate $b$, we need to know its entire prime factorisation: it allows us to conclude $a^3\mid b^2$ and therefore $b^2\geq a^3$. The intuition for this bound is the following: we know that $b\leq2a$, so if we can estimate $b\geq x\cdot a^y$ with $y>1$, then there's only finitely many cases left.

Comment: @barto Couldn't we have used a divisor $d$ that is not necessarily a degree of a prime number but could be a number that could be somehow expressed using two or more different prime numbers instead?

Comment: I'm not sure. When abandoning primes you lose their powers.